# SQL subqueries errors

Tags: sql, subquery, adventureworks

Using the AdventureWorks2012 database, I have to change the query below to select the       top 10% orders with CustomerId greater than 500 and sequence the orders by TotalDue in descending sequence.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
 INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail d 
 ON d.SalesOrderId = h.SalesOrderId
```

Here are two of my attempts at solving the problem, but both contain errors:

```
  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'.
  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

Attempt 1

```
 SELECT *
 FROM SalesOrderHeader 
 WHERE SalesOrderID IN
 (SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT SalesOrderID 
 FROM SalesOrderDetail 
 WHERE SalesOrderID > 500
 ORDER BY TotalDue DESC);
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

---

UPDATE:  I removed the comma from the ORDER BY section and managed to execute the query from my first attempt.  However, I get an seemingly endless "Executing Successfully" load.  In other words, I'm getting over 3000 results and counting when I modified the query below:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
    WHERE SalesOrderID IN
(SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT SalesOrderID 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
WHERE CustomerID > 500
ORDER BY TotalDue DESC);
```

Comment: At a quick glance, you don't put a comma between your sort column and your sort direction.  So you want `order by TotalDue DESC`. I think that may get you going on your first query.

Comment: Thank you.  That helped me solve part of my problem.  The query execution worked.